# How to add column based on dynamic column

Tags: sql, postgresql

An example of a simple one to simplify understanding of a question, in a real query it will be difficult to simply write "value + 20".

Example table

```
id | value |
-------------
 1 |   20  |
 2 |   30  |
```

Query example:

```
SELECT id, value, value + 10 as value1, value1 + 10 as value2
FROM table;
```

> Error: ERROR: column "value1" does not exist

Is there any way I can make this query work?

Comment: why not `value + 20 as [value2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use aliases defined in the `select` again in the same `select`, `where`, or `from` clauses (and many databases extend this to `group by` and `having`).

This is rule in SQL. You may wonder why, but here is a simple explanation for the `select`. Remember that SQL is defined around sets, which have no order. SQL simply does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select`. Without that guarantee, the engine doesn't know which is going to be evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an alias defined in a `SELECT` clause in the same clause.  So, just repeat your logic:

```
SELECT
    id,
    value,
    value + 10 AS value1,
    value + 20 AS value2
FROM table;
```

I don't know if this query represents your actual problem, or if it be a simplification.  If you had a complex expression in a select, and you really did not want to repeat it, then you could subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, value, value + 10 AS value1
    FROM table
)

SELECT *, value1 + 10 AS value2
FROM cte;
```